# Meteor POST does not send data

Tags: rest, meteor, flask, meteor-react

METEOR POST CALL

```
var postData = {
           "link" : "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dfddf/bhQJ5XDTg28vSr8Py/1531485d.pdf"
    }


      HTTP.call( 'POST', 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/add_message/hello', postData, 
         function( error, response ) {

         if ( error ) {
            console.log( error );
         } else {
            console.log( response);

         }
      });
```

FLASK API

```
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app,headers=['Content-Type'])

@app.route('/api/add_message/<uuid>', methods=['GET','POST'])
def add_message(uuid):
    req_data = request.get_json()
    return jsonify(req_data)
```

I have tried the same using Postman and cURL, both return the passed object correctly, but when using the meteor call I get a NONE on :

```
 request.get_json()
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by passing the object in a data key

```
{ 

data :{ 
        "link" : "blah"
      } 
}
```